# Get arch WorkManager running status

Tags: java, android, android-jobscheduler, android-workmanager

I recently started using arch WorkManager for my background processing. Since it's a newly introduced library,there are hardly any tutorials about it. I'm stuck here at a point. I have a service which checks for any data change in firebase. If service gets destroyed, WorkManager comes into action.
In my service's onDestroy method, i have-

```
        PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder photoWorkBuilder =
                new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(MyWorker.class, 10000,
                        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        PeriodicWorkRequest myWork = photoWorkBuilder.build();

        WorkManager.getInstance().enqueue(myWork);
```

I want to enqueue work ONLY IF, my previous status is null or not running. I don't want to clutter several works in queue. My above code creates Work queue each and every time my service is destroyed,so it will just queue up and up. Yes, i did read about tutorials for this but all of them were for Kotlin or had lambda expression. 
PS- Java method only, no Kotlin or lambda expression.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to get rid off Service completely and use WorkManager with periodic request to poll for changes. Also, if you are using Firebase Database, then you should be able to listen to database changes without need for Service. I followed [this example](https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/services-the-life-with-without-and-worker-6933111d62a6) for WorkManager. This article very well describes history behind WorkManager and shows one nice example.

Comment: How do i listen to database changes? If app goes idle or phone goes into deep sleep, there's no reaction to database change then

Comment: As per my understanding, syncing of data is handled by firebase database library. You need not do it explicitly.